# Zero element in the inner product space of all random variables with finite variance and $\langle X,Y\rangle = E(XY)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I want to prove that the set of all random variables with finite variance and $\langle X,Y\rangle = E(XY)$ is an inner product on this set.

I want to see that $\langle X,X \rangle = 0$ iff $X = 0$. My first problem is that I've never been told what the zero element of this space is.

The second problem is that when I write up the expectation
$$
0 = E(X^2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \underbrace{x^2}_{\geq 0} \underbrace{f(x)}_{\geq 0} dx
$$
I feel that this can only be true if the integrand is zero almost everywhere and this the function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ apart from $x=0$. This is a problem because then the probability distribution would no longer be normalized:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) dx + \int_{0}^0 f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0
$$

Can someone please help me clarify what the zero element is, and how to deal with the paradox I describe?

Comment: You might want to require that the _variance_ be finite rather than that the mean be finite. Finite variance implies finite mean but the reverse implication is not true.

Comment: There is no paradox; consider a distribution with $p(x=0) = 1$ (a distribution with all its mass at 0.)  It certainly satisfies the "finite variance" criterion as well.   This answers your first question also.

Comment: Is a highly related question, "what's the density $f$ for a random variable that is zero [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)?" You have a short argument that you can't have a random variable such that $P(X=0) = 1$, but that's not right. One way to think about that may be the [delta dirac function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). The more rigorous way would be to go down the measure theory road...

Comment: Hint: The random variables need not be continuous as you have assumed in your work; a putative zero element would be a degenerate random variable that takes on value $0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Are you saying that the zero element of the space of all stochastic variables is the stochastic variable X which is 0 almost surely?

Comment: What you want to prove is not true.  What is true is that *equivalence classes* of random variables (up to "almost sure" equality) form a Hilbert space with this inner product.  That is why you are correct to write "this can only be true if the integrand is zero almost everywhere": any such integrand is a representative of the equivalence class of zero.  See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Lebesgue_spaces.